BigQuery Returns Different Results On every execution for Exactly same query when using LIMIT
On running the exactly same query I get different results. 
Details:
Total results are 64155
since I am using Cube.js as my backend with big Query which has retrieval limit of 50k rows per query , I am trying to retrieve them in two steps. On fetching first batch of 50k rows I get different result on every execution
IF I don't use Limit Results are Ok. 
Findings: 
Cache is turned off
Query 1: 
select count(*), sum(fact__values_sum) from (
SELECT
      `dim_product`.PH_1 `dim_product__ph_1`, 
      `dim_product`.PH_3 `dim_product__ph_3`, 
      `dim_geography`.H1_8 `dim_geography__h1_8`, 
      `dim_measure`.label `dim_measure__label`,
      `dim_time_period`.label `dim_time_period__label`,
      `dim_geography`.H1_5 `dim_geography__h1_5`, 
      `dim_geography`.H1_6 `dim_geography__h1_6`, 
      DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME(`fact`.`reported_date`, 'UTC'), MONTH) `fact__reporteddate_month`, 
      sum(`fact`.values) `fact__values_sum`, 
      sum(`fact`.valuesly) `fact__values_ly_sum`, 
      sum(`fact`.valuespp) `fact__values_p_p_sum`
    FROM
      plexus-336107.plexusdata.fact AS `fact`
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_product AS `dim_product` ON `fact`.product_id = `dim_product`.id
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_geography AS `dim_geography` ON `fact`.geography_id = `dim_geography`.id
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_measure AS `dim_measure` ON `fact`.measure_id = `dim_measure`.id
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_time_period AS `dim_time_period` ON `fact`.time_period_id = `dim_time_period`.id  
WHERE (`fact`.`reported_date` >= TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z') 
AND `fact`.`reported_date` <= TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01T23:59:59.999Z')) 
AND (`fact`.data_type_id = CAST('100' AS FLOAT64)) 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 
ORDER BY 8 ASC LIMIT 50000  ) 
where dim_product__ph_1 ="Gucci" 
and dim_time_period__label='MTD' 
and dim_measure__label='Quantity Sold'

Query 1 Results:
results--> 2283   ,  24085.0
job_id -->bquxjob_476e8876_18ea056aa87

results--> 2263  , 23977.0
job_id--> bquxjob_78a92fd0_18ea0570760

Query 2:
select count(*), sum(fact__values_sum) from (

 SELECT
      `dim_product`.PH_1 `dim_product__ph_1`, 
      `dim_product`.PH_3 `dim_product__ph_3`, 
      `dim_geography`.H1_8 `dim_geography__h1_8`, 
      `dim_measure`.label `dim_measure__label`, 
      `dim_time_period`.label `dim_time_period__label`, 
      `dim_geography`.H1_5 `dim_geography__h1_5`, 
      `dim_geography`.H1_6 `dim_geography__h1_6`, 
      DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME(`fact`.`reported_date`, 'UTC'), MONTH) `fact__reporteddate_month`, 
      sum(`fact`.values) `fact__values_sum`, 
      sum(`fact`.valuesly) `fact__values_ly_sum`, 
      sum(`fact`.valuespp) `fact__values_p_p_sum`
    FROM
      plexus-336107.plexusdata.fact AS `fact`
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_product AS `dim_product` ON `fact`.product_id = `dim_product`.id
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_geography AS `dim_geography` ON `fact`.geography_id = `dim_geography`.id
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_measure AS `dim_measure` ON `fact`.measure_id = `dim_measure`.id
LEFT JOIN plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_time_period AS `dim_time_period` ON `fact`.time_period_id = `dim_time_period`.id  
WHERE `fact`.`reported_date` ="2023-01-01" 
AND (`fact`.data_type_id = CAST('100' AS FLOAT64)) 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 
ORDER BY 8 ASC LIMIT 50000  ) 
where dim_product__ph_1
="Gucci" 
and dim_time_period__label='MTD' 
and dim_measure__label='Quantity Sold'

Query 2 Results :
Job_id--> bquxjob_3e391a4c_18ea0511613
result--> 2297  25048.0
Job_id--> bquxjob_58310e22_18ea051eb25
result--> 2268  25329.0
Job_id--> bquxjob_3c8eb262_18ea052ba77
result--> 2269  24752.0

given  below are relevant schemas DDL
CREATE TABLE `plexus-336107.plexusdata.fact`
(
  reported_date TIMESTAMP,
  id INT64,
  category_id INT64,
  geography_id INT64,
  product_level_id INT64,
  time_period_id INT64,
  data_type_id INT64,
  product_id INT64,
  measure_id INT64,
  values FLOAT64,
  valuesLY FLOAT64,
  valuesPP FLOAT64,
  denomValue FLOAT64,
  denomValueLY FLOAT64,
  denomValuePP STRING,
  denomByMarket FLOAT64,
  denomByMarketLY FLOAT64,
  Flag INT64,
  org_id INT64,
  denomByMarketPP FLOAT64
);



CREATE TABLE `plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_geography`
(
  id INT64,
  country STRING,
  org_id INT64,
  H1_1 STRING,
  H1_2 STRING,
  H1_3 STRING,
  H1_4 STRING,
  H1_5 STRING,
  H1_6 STRING,
  H2_1 STRING,
  H2_2 STRING,
  H2_3 STRING,
  H2_4 STRING,
  H2_5 STRING,
  H2_6 STRING,
  data_type_id INT64
);

CREATE TABLE `plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_time_period`
(
  id INT64,
  period STRING,
  label STRING,
  granularity STRING,
  org_id INT64,
  data_type_id INT64
);


CREATE TABLE `plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_measure`
(
  id INT64,
  name STRING,
  `group` STRING,
  label STRING,
  org_id INT64,
  data_type_id INT64,
  non_additive STRING,
  level_order STRING
);



CREATE TABLE `plexus-336107.plexusdata.dim_product`
(
  id INT64,
  PH_1 STRING,
  PH_2 STRING,
  PH_3 STRING,
  PH_4 STRING,
  PH_5 STRING,
  PH_6 STRING,
  data_type_id INT64
);

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks In Advance

Hi - as a general point, please don’t use images in your question. For this specific question providing the ddl for the tables, as editable text, would have been more useful. Back to your actual question, if you are asking why multiple executions of the same query generate different results, it’s presumably because your inner query isn’t deterministic the way you’ve written it (it can produce different results each time you run it)

Thanks for the tip. Can you elaborate a little more on that? Any way to make it deterministic? Since i am only trying to fetch some data by applying filters from star schema database. Outer query is only for understanding purposes.

You would need to look at your data and work out why your query, against your data, is returning different results; as no-one else has access to your data it would be difficult for anyone else to help you. As an aside, I’m not sure why you are left joining your dims to your fact as this will impact performance, they should be inner joined

Unless you can identify a unique key for your results, and sort by that, you can't guarantee an exact order each time you run. If you can't do that, simply order by all columns: order by 8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

Thanks for the suggestions. I had to add all dims in order by for that

I got it working by adding all dims in order by. since current order by wasn't enough to gurantee exact same order
